# manually load .dll to use standard c++ container

Tags: c++, dll

I'm currently trying a real time sub system ( [Kithara](http://www.kithara.de/) ) in a Demo version.
Using this, in Kernel level, I can't access anything in link with Windows, and when I load a library I must load manually every other libraries needed by the first one.
Also, because memory allocation is handle by Windows, I cannot use classic new and delete operator.
I've created an allocator and tried to used it with a basic_string and with a vector :
std::vector >();

but my kernel is crashing when calling the constructor of the vector!
It say the kernel application tried to use a function from an external dll that is not available.
I'm currently contacting Kithara support to get some help but I wanted community help ( I am sure they will say to use their own KsVector and KsString, which are incredibly horrible!, and there is not only two container in the world ... )

So, someone have any idea of why I can't construct an empty vector without calling external code ?
I thought the vector code was all in headers, and that using an allocator would resolve allocation problem.

Comment: You've little hope of making this work. You've got the wrong language. C is your guy. What do you think will happen when you raise exceptions in your kernel mode code?

Comment: I must catch it first ^^. If I don't, I've install a "system handle", which call my own code when a task crash, it will show up a small box ( not very user friendly but at least it does'nt bluescreen ) with error informations. It's the same as using normal windows, but this time only the task ( the thread ) crash. But yes, if it crash in a kernel function ( not in a task ), it bluescreen